# Eclipse autofill some invalid tag

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed Linux Luna 4.4.1 on Linux Ubuntu 14.10. JDK 8 is installed not that it should matter.

The problem is that when I make a main-function in a class, it inserts some invalid space between the arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the invalid character is between String[] and args.
}
```

This gives me a compiler error when I run the program. "Syntax error on token "Invalid character", delete this token."

Has anyone else experienced this? Or maybe you have a fix? 
 Never had this problem with Windows Eclipse, so I think it's Ubuntu specific. When I remove the invalid character using backspace, and then add space again the error disappear.

Comment: How you are creating the main? writing main and then ctr+space, checking the box to create a main method while creating class or copying from somewhere else?

Comment: I first create a class (without main-method checkbox ticked). Then I write the method out by my self. It happens only the first time I create the main-method. If I delete the whole method and write it again, the error disappear and the program runs.

Comment: You type the main method fully by hand and the character is inserted? No keyboard shortcuts at all?

Comment: Correct. No shortcuts.

Comment: Can you please edit your post with a sample java class with line numbers and also the exception trace? Sounds really strange.

Comment: I will surely do it, but what is "exception trace"?.

Comment: Just found out using copy-pasting the invalid character that it is "NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE" as opposed to "SPACE" which is the normal space character.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the Eclipse's template for main methods.  You can view/edit it here:

1. Goto Eclipse > Preferences...
2. Select Java > Editor > Templates
3. In the template list select "main"
4. Click "Edit..."

You should should be able to remove the offending character there.

Comment: Sorry i missed that you were typing the main method by hand and not inserting it.  
What is your encode set to in Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding?

Comment: It is set to Default (UTF-8). As I commented on the thread above. I pasted in the illegal character and found out it is called "narrow no-break space". I think that eclipse "converts" space into this character, however, the compiler does not agree.